# How to overlay fillable checkpoints on a progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a progress bar with several 'checkpoints'.

[image]

I want the checkpoints to be filled linearly as the progress bar reaches reach point in a way which appears natural. As the progress bar fills from left to right, it should fill a checkpoint and then stop until it receives some further user interaction.

I previously used jQuery to fill each checkpoint when the progress bar reached it by applying a CSS class to it when the progress fill animation was over. This looked very amateur though. I want to make the same fill animation is applied to both the progress bar and the checkpoint it stops at.

How can I do this using pure CSS?

```
<div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar">
                <div class="progress-indicator item-0"></div>
                <div class="progress-indicator item-1"></div>
                <div class="progress-indicator item-2"></div>
                <span class="progress-bar-fill-area" style="width: 22.5%;"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Are you really asking how to fill a circle with color from one side?

Comment: Instead of explaining what you are doing, show your current code, please.

Comment: ^^ The CSS that you have so far would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider base64 encoded images in CSS as pure CSS, you can use them as a mask, by overlaying them over your progress-bar.

```js
var n = 0;
setInterval(function() {
 var bar = document.querySelector(".progress");
 bar.classList.remove("step" + ((n + 4) % 5));
 bar.classList.add("step" + n);
 n = (n + 1) % 5;
}, 2000);
```

```css
.progress-bar {
 width: 500px;
 height: 32px;
 background-color: gray;
 position: relative;
}

.progress-indicator {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAH0AAAAgCAYAAAA/kHcMAAABFUlEQVRo3u3YPW6DMBiAYX8VMyLeQb4DopUyVaIsmfFteoWexGLuQL1GSiNfAg6A2JHcsR36k6FSVed9Vjz51YcNUtd1VLgqN2wB0UF0EB1EB9FBdBAdRAfR8QtERGmtvTHmEEKQEIIYYw5aay8i7+v4DZuGLMu2qqr2zrnzZ8+ttc00Tcdt2zImPZEJL8uy+yq4Uko5585VVe1FhElPQVEUr977u0vWdl33wo4BAJDIxY+L3P+ntfbjOD5csrZt2xOfbAlYlqW11jY/rev7/n5d11uiJyDGqKZpOn4X3lrbzPM8xhh5vSd1Vouo3W7n8zx/Gobh+cN0Py7L0sYYOdOvFa93ooPoIDqIDqKD6CA6iI4/9AZ+BlVJ/MotKwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
 float: left;
}

.progress-bar-fill-area {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 background-color: #63BC62;
 width: 0%;
}

.step1 .progress-bar-fill-area {
 width: 25%;
 transition: width 1s;
}

.step2 .progress-bar-fill-area {
 width: 50%;
 transition: width 1s;
}

.step3 .progress-bar-fill-area {
 width: 75%;
 transition: width 1s;
}

.step4 .progress-bar-fill-area {
 width: 100%;
 transition: width 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
 <div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="progress-bar-fill-area"></div>
  <div class="progress-indicator"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```